# Multiple mirrors in a three.js scene kills performance

Tags: three.js, mirror

Based on the [mirror example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=mirr#webgl_mirror) in three.js, I have recreated a good old [praxinoscope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOItdZOGnx8) "movie projector", where a column of mirrors reflect a short sequence of images to create the illusion of movement.

In version 84 of three.js, this works quite well.

**Example using v84: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/eEbjba**
[image]

In version 85 however, there were some changes to [Mirror.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/Mirror.js), and in later versions all the mirrors (8 mirrors in this case) make the praxinoscope really slow (low FPS).

**Example using v87: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/vJvozR**
[image]

I suspect the slow performance has to do with a lot of recursive calls and unneeded rendering starting with calls to a `onBeforeRender()` function from `Mirror.js`. Stacktrace:

[image]

If you look at the code, mirrors are created and added in the `addMirrorAndImage()` function. Is there a better way to add mirrors, or some other trick that will give the same performance as the older (pre v85) version?

- v84: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/eEbjba
- v87: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/vJvozR

Comment: If you feel reasonably confident there has been a three.js regression, it would be appropriate to file this as a bug report on the three.js site.

Comment: @WestLangley - Thanks, I have submitted an issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in v88 (`Mirror` renamed to `Reflector`): https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/dZYKwP